# Clone GitLab repo & modify selected files then push with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitlab

I am trying to clone all the projects of a specific group of GitLab and then trying to modify all the `.yaml` files & `.txt` files by adding a `comment` in the top of the selected files.

However I am not sure if I am going through the right approach.

I am able to clone all the gitlab repositories but not sure how I can write comments in the beginning of the selected files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import gitlab
import subprocess

glab = gitlab.Gitlab(f'http://GitLabInstance', f'PAT')
groups = glab.groups.list()
groupname = 'MY_GROUP' 
for group in groups:
    if group.name == groupname:
        projects = group.projects.list(all=True)

for repo in projects:
    command = f'git clone {repo.ssh_url_to_repo} -b master'
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output, _ = process.communicate()
    process.wait()

text = 'sample comment'
os.system('find . -name ".txt"')

f = open("textfile.txt","a") 
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

However, with the current script which I am trying, I am only able to write modify only one file where I am writing the comment in the end of the line.

1. Is there any way we can make this script as generic python script so that we can make use of it for normal git too and not for gitlab? What changes needs to be made for that?
2. How can I pass all the files which are coming as output of `find . -name ".txt"` , because I want to add that comment on top for all such files.
3. How to push it back to the master branch automatically as part of script itself.

I went through so much of documentation regarding writing in files of python but looks like we can only append in the end and not in beginning, The only possible solutions I am getting is where I need to rewrite the contents of a file again by deleting it or by cutting and pasting it which I find very disastrous.

I am new to the world of python and finding it little difficult to manage things from here.

Thanks

Comment: you are writing to only one file. Once cloned, you have to open all the files u want to write to and modify their contents. If you are asking how to loop over a files in a directory check out `os.listdir(path)`.

Comment: You can generate yourself a TOKEN at `/-/profile/personal_access_tokens` then make use of Gitlab's API [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository)

Comment: Note that the word *append* literally means *add to the end*. You cannot "append" at the front of something; such an operation is an "insert", not an "append". Most file systems do not support insert operations directly.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your questions -

1. There is nothing specific to gitlab in the script except that the repositories reside in gitlab. You are still using git to clone. Only the URL of the repo will change and that is non specific to git.
2. Instead of doing `find`, use `os.listdir()` which will return all the fiels in an array whicch you can then filter for the extension `.txt`

```
In [1]: fs = os.listdir('/home/ninan/try/')

In [2]: fs
Out[2]: ['not.xls', 'somefile.txt']

In [3]: all_txt = [file for file in fs if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.txt']

In [4]: all_txt
Out[4]: ['somefile.txt']
```

3. You cloned them in a loop, push to the same repos in a loop.

Writing in beginning of a file:

```
❯ cat somefile.txt                                                                                        
   1   │ I am a file
   2   │ blah blah
   3   │ check this out


~/try 
❯
```

From my pyconsole:
Just put the In statements to your script

```
In [1]: f = open(path, 'r+')

In [1]: lines = f.readlines()

In [2]: f.seek(0)
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: f.write("I am a line at the beginning. I am the alpha and not the omega\n\n")
Out[3]: 62

In [4]: for line in lines: # write old content after new
    ...:     f.write(line)
    ...: 

In [5]: f.close()
```

Catting the file after the above execution:

```
   1   │ I am a line at the beginning. I am the alpha and not the omega
   2   │ 
   3   │ I am a file
   4   │ blah blah
   5   │ check this out
```

Another simple way is :

```
with open(path, 'r') as f: lines = f.read()
with open(path, 'w') as f: f.write("I am a line at the beginning. I am the alpha and not the omega\n" + lines)
```

To recursively search in directories:

Check out `fnmatch` or you can do this with plain python also using `os.walk()` -

```
[os.path.join(root, file) for root, dirname, dir in os.walk(folder) for file in dir if file.endswith(".txt")]
```

Comment: Hi @leoOrion, thanks a lot. Your answer is very helpful. Can you tell me how can I recursively search in my directory? because I want to search for `.txt` file in all my sub directories too, with `all_txt = [file for file in fs if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.txt']` I am only able to look for files which are present under my listdir. thanks

Comment: Edited my answer for recursively searching through sub dirs

Comment: Hi @leoOrion, thanks now I am able to recursively loop through the directories, but can you tell me how can I loop through the all_txt paths which I have to pass it under the `f = open(path,r+)` so that I am able to write inside it. Thanks

Comment: Are u asking how to use a for loop ?

Comment: Yes. I am asking how can I loop the `all_txt` which is having all the paths of files which needs to be added with the `#test comments in the beginning`

Comment: i can see you know abt for loops frm ur question. Modify it to work over the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240744/discussion-between-sameer-atharkar-and-leoorion).